# Como faço para assinar digitalmente um arquivo .pem usando o algoritimo SHA256

Tags: vb.net, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital

Tenho um arquivo .pem convertido de um certificado digital A3(.pfx)
Preciso assinar 2 CNPJs concatenados usando esse arquivo .pem, que nele contem 2 Chaves 1 Publica e outra Privada, preciso usar a chave privada para fazer a assinatura dos CNPJs, que no caso ele irá gerar uma assinatura em base64.
Existe um metodo de fazer isso usando o OpenSSL, segue o link:https://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#digest-sign.
Mas no caso queria saber se seria possível fazer isso na linguagem do VB.net ou em C#, Em VB eu importei(Imports System.Security.Cryptography), mas não consegui dar continuidade.
Alguém teria uma dica?

Comment: Veja se esse um desses links te ajudam: ["Cryptographic Signatures"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk8wx38z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (mais baixo nível) ou ["How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (mais alto nível, para assinar documentos XML). Ambos possuem exemplos em C# e VB.

Comment: <https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1> Verifica aí pois tem um exemplo no site da Microsoft